# How do I have a different color for selected cells and why does it crash?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can change the color when a cell is selected, but when I click on another cell, I need the previous cell to go to the original color before it got selected. When I select a cell and scroll all the way down where that selected cell is not visible and click on another cell I get an error. Look below for error.

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: selectcell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell
    cell.viewcheck.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell: selectcell = table.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell // fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
    cell.viewcheck.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

Comment: Store a reference to the cell's previous colour when you select it and then use that stored colour to reset the colour when the cell is deselected.

Comment: try `cell.selected = true` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and then set the `backgroundColor`. Now in `didDeselectRowAtIndexPath` method `cell.selected = false` and then set the `backgroundColor`.

Comment: @Santosh it is crashing, the crash error is above

Answer (score 0):

You may consider trying the `selectedBackgroundView` property on the `UITableViewCell` class. You can do the below in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, to set the whole cell to a specific color upon selection:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as! selectcell
   let background = UIView(frame: cell.frame)
   background.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
   cell.selectedBackgroundView = background

   return cell
}
```

If you have any questions, please ask!

Comment: @manatee you should try my answer in cellForRowAtIndexPath not in didSelectRowAtIndexPath. You also need to remove the code you showed in your example from your project. My answer attempts to solve the problem without needing to adjust the color manually when the row is selected.

Comment: So you removed the didSelectRowAtIndexPaths from your code and replaced your cellForRowAtIndexPath with the one in my answer, and multiple cells where selected? @manatee

Comment: Yes I did and it allowed for multiple selections. After I click one cell it turned black then When I clicked another cell it also turned black but the previous cell stayed black instead of turning white

Comment: So you want multiple selection of cells, but you don't want to highlight multiple cells? @manatee

Comment: No the user should only be able to select one cell at a time and that cell should be a different color. When they click another cell then that cell should be the only cell with a different color

Comment: Set Selection in the Table View's properties in Interface builder to "Single Selection" to achieve that. @manatee

Answer (score 0):

Try this, although ultimately it sounds like your datasource (whether it is an array or whatever) isn't working right.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, shouldHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool {
        let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell
        cell.cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        return true
    }

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell
    cell.cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell
    cell.cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell
    cell.cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell
    cell.cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> NSIndexPath? {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! selectcell
    cell.cardView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    return indexPath
}
```